# Stuck on exercise: Inertia of laminates described by polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am currently taking my first calculus class as a first semester maths student. The following questions is from the book Calculus: Early Transcendentals, on the chapter regarding applications of double integrals.
Question is written as stated:
*Find the polar moment of inertia $I_0$ of the indicated lamina.*
*The region bounded by the right-hand loop of the lemniscate $r^2=cos(2\theta);\delta(x,y)=r^2$.*

The given laminate can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oibf3.gif).

From what i understand the inertia can be described as the following in polar coordinates:
$$I_0=\iint_R r^2\delta(x,y)r \,dr\,d\theta$$
If i were to plug in the given information, i would find the following iterated integral:
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{cos(2\theta)}}  r^2r^2rdrd\theta$$
Here i define the bounds for r as the positive solution to the given $r^2$ equation. Meanwhile the $\theta$ limits are given by the question, as the regions is in the first and fourth quadrant.

However, I realise that this is wrong as it computes to 0. Any tips on how to move further along with this?
Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits for $\theta$ should be
$$
  -\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}.
$$
Note that the right part of the lemniscate lies between the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$.
I believe the picture you included isn't correct.

Also, from an algebraic point of view we see the limits weren't correct. Note that $\cos(2\theta)$ becomes negative when $\pi/4<\theta \leq \pi/2$ or $ -\pi/2\leq \theta < -\pi/4$, so $\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}$ is not defined for these values.

Comment: Thank you, I realize the mistake now. I've now found the answer $1/9$, but the book gives the answer $2/9$, do you reckon, that the point of the question was for the whole region of the $r^2$ expression, given the description in the original question?

Comment: I don't see an immediate mistake right now, and I also obtain $1/9$. But if you consider the whole lemniscate, then the value indeed becomes $2/9$.

Comment: Alright, thank you. A comment to your answer; it appears you put a small mistake in your limit, as you write $-\frac{-\pi}{4}$, I however disregarded the extra added minus.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. I will correct the typo! Thanks for noting.